# Проектирование базы данных "Автостоянка"

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

По заданию необходимо спроектировать базу данных "Автостоянка", для которой есть документы "Договор с клиентом", "Квитанция об оплате услуги автостоянки", "Электронная регистрация на въезде по гос. номеру автомобиля". Договор составляется на определенный период и, возможно, на несколько автомобилей, оплата услуг по договору может осуществляться частями. После определения всех атрибутов, а также функциональных зависимостей, я построил следующую схему БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преподаватель сказал следующее:

- "номер тарифа" определяется "номер договора", а не "номером платежа";
- "площадь парковочного места" зависит только от "номера парковочного места" (как я понял - в отношении "Парковочные места" нарушена 2НФ);
- "гос. номер автомобиля" желательно не использовать, поскольку внешними данными мы не можем управлять;
- все парковочные места, оформленные на договор, оплачиваются сразу

Основная загвоздка состоит в том, что мне не понятно, как правильно организовать оформление на один договор несколько парковочных мест (если у клиента несколько автомобилей). Постоянно на этом моменте ошибаюсь. Преподаватель в первую очередь обращает внимание на функциональные зависимости, а мне не особо понятно как правильно их строить, поскольку опыта в их построении раньше не было.

Comment: Вижу противоречия в условии: 1) "оплата услуг по договору может осуществляться частями" и "все парковочные места, оформленные на договор, оплачиваются сразу"; 2) "регистрация на въезде по гос. номеру автомобиля" и "гос. номер автомобиля желательно не использовать" 3) "Квитанция об оплате услуги автостоянки" противоречит договорному характеру работы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну давайте проектировать.

1. Договоры

- Номер договора
- Номер клиента
- Номер тарифа
- Сумма договора
- Дата начала
- Дата окончания

2. Договоры Парковочные места

- Номер Договора Парковочного места
- Номер Договора
- Номер Парковочного места

3. Парковочные места

- Номер Парковочного места
- Площадь Парковочного места

4. Тариф

- номер тарифа
- наименование

5. Платежи

- номер платежа
- номер договора
- сумма
- дата платежа

6. Клиент

- номер клиента
- имя
- прочие данные

7. Автомобили

- номер автомобиля
- номер клиента
- регистрационный номер
- прочие данные

8. Допуски

- номер допуска
- номер договора
- номер автомобиля

9. Регистрация проезда

- номер регистрации проезда
- номер допуска
- номер Парковочного места
- дата проезда
- дата выезда

Как-то так. Стрелки и прочие детали можете добавить сами.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем понял, за что ответственно 2-е отношение, не могли бы вы пожалуйста уточнить?

Comment: 2. Это много ко многим. У вас парковочные места могут быть во многих договорах, и Договора состоять из многих парковочных мест

Comment: Для этого вводится дополнительная таблица. Договор парковочное место чтоб парковки сами по себе не зависили от договора. Не то у вас они зависят

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятно. А эту таблицу можно как-то интерпретировать / назвать иначе?

Comment: Вообще-то вы б назвали ваши таблицы иначе все бы норм выглядило

Comment: А как их иначе можно было назвать?  Преподаватель по поводу этого никаких замечаний не делал. У меня в основном проблема в таблице парковочные места. Изначально, там был номер договора и номер парковочного места. Однако, преподаватель сказал, что номер парковочного места никак не может функционально определять номер договора.

Comment: Назовите как считаете правильным. Задание ваше и сдавать не мне.